# Developing custom functions in NFC

Tags: nfc, ndef

I watched a youtube video: http://youtube.com/watch?v=td_O6m6zDLo

It shows how NFC works with the device. Opening app and etc. But what if I want to develop my own NFC tag with functions like, for example, store user's Facebook profile link and when tap on tag, it will like a particular page.

Based on my understanding towards NFC, I have to write codes for the tag and the reader reads the codes in the tag and perform some actions or functions written in the tag (correct me if I am wrong).

I browsed through this website
http://www.buynfctags.com/bundles/gototags-nfc-encoder-starter-kit.html
and this
http://www.identivenfc.com/en/nfc-software-development-kit-sdk/nfc-solutions-development-kit-sdk.htm

My question is that can I develop the function mentioned above using the software from the website if I buy it?

Note that: It won't be an Andriod device. It will be like (I think) the reader and the tag. And I will be writing codes for the tag (correct me if I am wrong).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you refer to NFC tags containing NDEF messages (as specified by the NFC Forum).

A typical NFC tag scenario would involve work on both sides, the tag and the reader.

You would create an NDEF message that you initially write on the tag. An NDEF message is a static data structure (see [here](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Understanding_NFC_Data_Exchange_Format_%28NDEF%29_messages)) that could contain URLs, text, commands, data, etc. relevant to your application.

You then need an application on the reader side that reads the NDEF message from the tag, interprets the data structure and triggers some actions based on the NDEF message. Many smartphone platforms typically contain an application component that perfroms the reading and some initial parsing of received NDEF messages. Moreover, usually certain NDEF records are automatically handled by standard applications. E.g. URLs are usually automatically opend in a web browser, business cards are usually automatically opend in the address book app, etc.

If your target platform does not automatically handle a specific record type, you would need to write your own application that processes the record and triggers the appropriate actions. Similarly, if your platfrom does not automatically process NDEF messages from  NFC tags at all, you would need to create your own application that does this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I see the bigger picture now. So if I buy the software and SDK, am I able to write the application and the messages myself? Or just the message itself?

Comment: The GoToTags encoder will just allow you to write NDEF messages to tags there is no abstraction layer included that will help you write software for reading the tags (though you could still do that with the reader hardware that's included). The Identive SDK will give you programming interfaces to access NFC tags for both reading and writing and also contains demo applications that show that functionality.